# In the CourseGrade class how to use the addStudentScore() method? do we have to consider the parameters as array?

Tags: interface, aggregation

In the CourseGrade class how to use the addStudentScore() method? do we have to consider the parameters as array? we don't have any studentName or score declared in the class then how to use the addStudentScore() method?

[image]

Comment: Shows a parameter being passed into the method?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a new score (of type "int") to the scores array?